# How to calculate number of Days until a Date in future?

Tags: objective-c

Something does not add up.

I need to know how many days are there until Dec 21, 2012

```
NSDateFormatter *df= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSDate *dec21 = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 

dec21 = [df dateFromString:@"2012-12-21"];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];


NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:today
                                              toDate:dec21 options:0];
NSInteger days = [components day];
NSInteger months = [components month];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"About %d months and %d days left", months, days];
```

This code suggests there is still 129 months remaining.

What am i missing?

Comment: It's the mayans, messing with you.

Comment: In C# it would be int days = (dec21 - date).TotalDays;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date formatter does not have a format set, so it is not returning an NSDate of 21st December. Add the following line after you have created the formatter:

```
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
```

And you're set, until your next problem, which is that the result now says:

> About 2 months and 11 days left

You need to include the years as well and add that to the months figure to get an actual time left if you are only going to count in months and days.

Comment: Year translates to "2147483647". All this seems overly complicated. Is this the simplest Obj-C gives us?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the answer. The date format was wrong. And that value you're getting for the year doesn't look right, have you included the `NSYearCalendarUnit` in the unit flags?